# Stop TextJoin at 32K characters and continue in the next cell

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

OK, So I don't know where to start with this, not asking anyone to write the code for me, but I have a project at work with thousands of word documents. Some of which have over a million characters, some have 2000 characters. I need to put them all in a spreadsheet. I have a code that uploads the word documents to the spreadsheet, then it uses text join and creates a few helper cells. The VBA copy and pastes the helper cells to the database tab, then deletes all the data and uploads the next word doc, runs in a loop till all are done.

Here is my problem. Text join only allows you to have 32767 characters, any more and I just get a "CALC!" Error. So with so many helper cells I would like to just have VBA do the text join for me but stop at 32K characters and move to the next cell. How would I go about doing this. If there is another thread you can link if someone has done this please do so, if not just some direction and I'll run with it from there.

Comment: This is not going to help you, you will need to show the code and where it goes wrong..

Comment: What I can say now before seeing your code is, avoid use Textjoin, try use for loop, &. VBA should be able to handle a long string up to 2GB.